# Backup virtualbox virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox, backup

> The virtual machine 'test' has terminated unexpectedly during startup
>   with exit code 1 (0x1).

I keep getting this error after a windows update, in Windows 10.

Based on this, https://community.oracle.com/message/12761564#12761564
I have to uninstall virtualbox. My question is, how can  backup the Virtual Machines I created? Will it get lost after uninstalled?

I have 3 VM saved in my VB.

Comment: They are loose files. Depending on where you allowed them to save, you will find them on your harddisk. Usually %appdata%\VirtualBox. Also, if it is one of those major windows upgrades, you need to reinstall or update VirtualBox to fix it. If you upgrade to a newer virtualbox version, it will obviously detect all machines and you can continue to work.

Comment: Uninstalling VirtualBox will not remove your virtual machines.  Worth pointing out you can simply install the current version of VirtualBox without uninstalling the installation you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

Installing or uninstalling VirtualBox will not touch your virtual machines. Once done, you might have to ‘Add’ them back, and that’s it.

Of course, this assumes that you don’t manually delete them, or format the disk they are on.

If you want to back them up (which is generally a good idea, not just for upgrades), you need to find their location, and simply copy the complete directory to a backup location.